# Why does string before \v escape character at the end show that there is a virus in the file?

Tags: c, escaping, compiler-warnings, antivirus, virus

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    printf("h\a");
    printf("h2\v");
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening and I am using the DevC++ compiler of Bloodshed.inc

Please explain the logic and reason behind this.

I tried to get a normal execution of escape characters.
I was expecting to execute the statement to give a bell sound and print a vertical tab.
But my anti-virus software detected a virus and the terminal showed:

```
--------------------------------
Failed to execute "C:\Users\123445678\OneDrive\Desktop\File\h.exe":
Error 225: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I have a feeling this program is so small it matches some kind of virus pattern. Try adding more code.

Comment: " I was expecting to execute the statement to give a bell sound" -->  or play a .wav file file perhaps.  Take out `"\a"` and see if re-compile produces "Error 225:".

Comment: So, without the `\v` you can compile and execute the code without problems? Else, it may be your "inc" file or some tools you are using are "infected". Note: with new compiler versions and new libraries, we may get false positives (for antivirus companies may take some months to correct such false positives)

Answer (score 1):

Your anti-virus software is reporting a false positive.

Comment: That should rather be a comment. But actually it **is** the answer to the problem, so I upvoted anyway.